# string_agg function with IN operator not working in PostgreSQL Query

Tags: postgresql-9.1

here is my query

```
select * 
from table 
where id  in ( select  string_agg(CAST(id as varchar), '","') FROM table)
```

Comment: That query makes no sense at all. It's a complicated way of writing `select * from table where id is not null`

Answer (score 0):

`string_agg()` is completely useless and unnecessary for that:

```
select * 
from table_one
where id  in (select id FROM other_table)
```

---

I assume you are doing that for two *different* tables, otherwise that would be a very expensive way of writing: `select * from table where id is not null`

Comment: this is simple query but that's is not my real query
i want to run this simple query table is on both side not 2 different tables

select * 
from table 
where id  in ( select  string_agg(CAST(id as varchar), '","') FROM table)

Comment: @fawad: if you use the same table for both "sides" the query makes no sense whatsoever. And even then `string_agg()` is completely unnecessary. If that's not your real query then [**EDIT**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46292783/edit) your question and add the **real** query, some sample data and the expected output. If you ask for a query you are not actually using you won't get the answer that helps you. (Again: [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46292783/edit) your question do **NOT** post code or additional information in comments)